# Bean Creation exception, Injection of autowired dependency failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using spring hibernate in my application. I used all the required jar files but still getting bean creation exception saying the following:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'voteController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mindtree.service.VoteService com.mindtree.controller.VoteController.voteService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'voteServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mindtree.dao.VoteDao com.mindtree.serviceImpl.VoteServiceImpl.voteDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'voteDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate com.mindtree.daoImpl.VoteDaoImpl.hibernateTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the stacktrace:

```
 nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
```

The class `GenericObjectPool` is missing in your classpath.

So you have to add the `commons-pool.jar` to your project which contains this class.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, **read the stacktrace from the last line**, which will be the root cause of the problem. If you fix the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, by adding the respective jar file in your classpath, then it will work fine.